# What is the purpose of the "continue reading" button?

Tags: design, button

There is a trend in article sharing sites to partly hide articles beneath a continue reading button. What is the purpose of that?

I can understand that on a blog page with many articles to chose from such a feature makes sense. Although I'm seeing it in many "one article" pages nowadays. Let's say a visitor comes from a social networking site. Being interested by a shared article, he lands on a page where the text is partly hidden by such a button. In that specific case, what is the intended purpose?

Comment: Often these "continue reading" buttons require a (paid-for) subscription to continue. I assume that is not the case in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

Usually but not always, when you land to an article through a social media link, the reason of popping up a "Continue reading" button is that you confirm (in a camouflaged way) to give access in background scripts to run through you browser.

Sometimes the very same button is popping up with a text ad which urges your attention.

Furthermore to your initial question, other cases are that this button may functioning as "Like" farming for the website/blog's Facebook Page.

Comment: In addition: Loading a new page will possibly show new ads, which will result in more revenue. Or you might get other links to similar articles on that website which again might lead to you visiting more page generating more ad-based revenue